# ¿Como eliminar el salto de linea Windows para ponerlo de unix?

Tags: salto-de-linea, notepad++, cobol

Por mi trabajo uso la herramienta Record Editor cuando necesito editar ficheros de COBOL y me estoy encontrando un problema y es que los archivos que tienen campos "especiales" (si se ven en notepad++ se ven como nulos), cada vez que guardo un archivo me mete saltos de linea windows (CRLF) al final de cada linea y yo necesito SOLAMENTE cambiar de los finales de linea ese CRLF por el salto de linea Unix (LF).

Éste es mi fichero guardado con la herramienta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y éste es el original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Record editor para cargar la copy está así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado varias cosas y nada funcionav(esto me elimina muchas cosas mas del salto):

```
sed -e 's/.$//' PRUEBA > PRUEBA2
```

Y luego he probado tambien con el tr:

```
tr -d "\n\r" < $mifichero > $mifichero.txt
```

Se pueden eliminar con el notepad++ en la opcion de editar pero no se qué pasa que cuando los vuelvo a meter al record editor, fallan.

¿Alguien me puede iluminar?

Gracias!

Comment: parece un problema con la rutina que utilizas en cobol para escribir los archivos, podrias brindar mas informacion sobre como haces ese proceso?

Comment: Buenas! pues simplemente cargo la copy con el formato del archivo en el Record editor > Load cobol copybook> y en Binary Format pongo Open Cobol Microfocus (intel) en File structure pongo Text IO y en system pongo Mainframe. Si pudiera te añadiría una foto para verlo mejor

Comment: he añadido la foto del Record editor a la pregunta

Comment: `tr -d "\n\r"` te elimina el salto de linea al completo y no solo el retorno de carro, en el caso de `sed` debería ser mas especifico: `sed 's/\r$//'`. Yo suelo usar [dos2unix](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dos2unix.1.en) para esto, especialmente por la facilidad de cambiar la codificación de paso.